# Singularity in WSL

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've successfully installed singularity in WSL environment. When I'm trying to run a new container with this command or any other like from the installation guidelines of singularity

```
sudo singularity exec library://sylabsed/examples/lolcow cowsay "Fresh from the library!"
```

I got the following error:

> beeugene@DESKTOP-E8785R2:/mnt/c/Users/ebara$ sudo singularity exec
> library://sylabsed/examples/lolcow cowsay "Fresh from the library!"
>
> WARNING: failed to set O_CLOEXEC flags on image
>
> FATAL: container
> creation failed: hook function for tag sessiondir returns error:
> failed to create /usr/local/var/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs
> directory: mkdir /usr/local/var/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs: file
> exists

Any ideas on how to fix it?

I'm using Windows 10 version 10.0.18362 build 18362.

Singularity version 3.3.0-rc.1.449.g965588d4c

I've tried to remove the session dir but got the same error.

Comment: [Singularity documentation](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.3/user-guide/installation.html#install-on-windows-or-mac) doesn't look like it's supported. What version of WSL are you using? Which version of Windows are you running?

Comment: @Seth, I'm using Windows 10 version 10.0.18362 build 18362.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the same warning on Windows 10.0.17763.1039 and WSL when trying `singularity shell` on v3.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some features were not supported in WSL1. Now WSL2 is available globally (Windows 10 build 2004 (May 2020 update). Singularity works perfectly there as well as Docker.